# Can we set in-memory Mongodb set as primary and WiredTiger as a non-voting replica?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I need to do fast querying over collections with frequent changes. Fortunately, the size of these collections won't get too big. Also, I can afford to lose some data, and the architecture does not need to be fault tolerant. The biggest requirement is to increase transaction throughput to the maximum. I have 2 servers, one with a goodProcessor server and the other one smallProcessor server.

I am exploring setting:

- the master db as in-memory storage on goodProcessor server
- the replica of the master db as WiredTiger storage on smallProcessor server

Is this replication setting possible?

Comment: Note, when you query the collection, then the data is cached in RAM anyway, so you may not gain as much performance as you may expect. Focus on proper indexes.

Answer (score 1):

WiredTiger is the engine used in MongoDB for managing documents in RAM and you will have WiredTiger in every node in your Replica Set.

More information here: [Replication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/replication/)

You can try with Write concern 0 ({w:0}) and that will speed things up at a cost (consistency).[Write concerns](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/write-concern/)

You need at least 3 nodes in your Replica Set, if you're not interested in having replication, then you can have a single node.

If you want to improve performance, use indexes, those are loaded into memory.

Comment: Of course, you can run a Replica Set with only 2 nodes. You just don't get high availability which is typically the main reason for using a Replica Set.